# One-dimensional packing problem: Optimal decomposition of music structure

Tags: algorithms, heuristics, packing, decomposition, optimal-strategy

I am currently working on my Master thesis on the visualization of music structure and I'm looking to find an optimal description of repetitions found in a piece of music.

### Problem Description

Given a section range in a song in seconds (or samples) , e.g. [10,20], I can look up where this section is repeated. Then we end up with a set of repeating sections like: [[10,20], [40,50], [70,80]]. We call this a **group**. A group has a certain **fitness** given to it.

*(As a sidenote, the fitness of a group is defined as a combination of the sum of similarity values and how much of the song they cover alltogether)*

Our goal is to find a set of **disjoint** groups that altogether have the **highest fitness**; the optimal decomposition of the repetitions. Below are two different valid decompositions of the same song, one course, and one fine decomposition.

[image: Course decomposition]

[image: Fine decomposition]

We are provided with a set of all candidate groups, here's a small selection, sorted top to bottom by fitness:
[image: Example of candidates]

### Current Greedy Method

1. Sort all candidates by fitness
2. Pick group *G* with the highest fitness
3. Remove any groups from candidates if they have overlap with *G*
4. Repeat from step 2 until no candidates are left

### Bonus

Sometimes the candidates overlap every so slightly, which in the context should perhaps not immediately lead to disqualification.

[image: Example of slight overlap]

There are options to relax the no-overlap rule. Note that each of the sections in a group has a different brightness. This brightness corresponds to a confidence, so in a group some sections are more certain to be proper repetitions than others.

For a group of sections *G* that we wish to add to a set of groups of sections *S*, we can:

- simply remove sections from *G* if they overlap with any sections in *S*
- trim the sides of to-be-added sections from *G* if they overlap with any sections in *S*
- keep the overlapping sections in *G*

I hope this problem is interesting enough to you to give it a shot!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If $n'$ is the number of groups, this problem admits no $2^{o(n')}$-time algorithm for any choice of a constant $\epsilon > 0$, unless the exponential time hypothesis (ETH) fails.

Let $G = (V, E)$ be an undirected graph with $n$ vertices $v_1, \dots, v_n$ and $m$ edges $e_1, \dots, e_m$.

Construct an instance of your problem  by creating $n'=n$ groups as follows:

- For each vertex $v_i \in V$, add a new group with fitness $1$ containing all intervals $[j-1, j]$ where $j$ is such that $v_i$ is an endpoint of $e_j$.

Any independent set $S \subseteq V$ of $G$ induces of collection of non-intersecting groups (except for the boundaries of the intervals) with total fitness $|S|$.
On the converse, any subset of $S'$ non-intersecting groups must have total fitness $|S'|$ and induces an independent set of size $|S'|$ in $G$.

The claim follows since, assuming the ETH, [there exists no $2^{o(n)}$-time algorithm for independent set](http://www.cs.bme.hu/%7Edmarx/papers/survey-eth-beatcs.pdf).

Moreover, assuming $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$, the above reduction also shows that for any constant $\epsilon>0$ there exists no polynomial-time $n^{1-\epsilon}$-approximation algorithm for your problem, even in the special case of unitary fitness. See, e.g., [here](https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/COMPEND/COMPED15/NODE29.HTM#1591).

Comment: In your construction, two groups intersect if there is a path of length 2 in $G$ between the two vertices. To fix this, you can associate vertex $v_i$ with a list $[j-1,j]$ for all edges $e_j$ incident to $i$.

Comment: Thanks! I just added the interval $[i-1, i]$ in the group of $v_i$. This should fix it.

Comment: If $(i,j),(j,k) \in E$ then $[j-1,j]$ would appear both in the group of $v_i$ and in the group of $v_k$.

Comment: D'oh! I see it now... thanks.

Comment: Thanks you for the nice problem transformation and proof. However, I am still having trouble understanding your construction. 
First of all, why do you create the group with fitness 0?
If I understand correctly, every edge $(v_i, v_j) \in E$ intuitively denotes that there is overlap between the two groups. Does the $e_j$ that you define not imply that there can only be two groups that share $[j-1,j]$?
I also realize that it would probably help to work with a group being a single set of integers instead of a set of ranges, does that change your approach?

Comment: Also I'd like to add that I'm still looking for an algorithm to use in getting an approximate solution, be it not one in polynomial time. I assume there are better options than the greedy strategy?

Comment: Sorry, the $0$ was a typo. It should be $1$. Yes, in my reduction each interval is shared by exactly 2 groups. If each group is a set of integers noting changes: just le the group of $v_i$ be $\{j : v \mbox{ is an endpoint of } e_j\}$.

Comment: Just a train of thought; would you perhaps know how to go about extending the problem to also allow overlap but with a certain cost? E.g. for two groups $A$ and $B$ the cost $c(A,B) = \frac{A \cap B}{A \cup B}$. In your reduction this would map to a complete graph with edge weights. Would there still be a definition for an optimal solution?

Comment: What would the overall measure to be (maximized) be in this case?

Comment: Sorry for being a bit vague.
It would be something like this:
Given a candidate optimal set of vertices $S$ the score $s(S)$ would be given by:
$s(S) = \frac{\sum_{v_i \in S}f(v_i)}{c+a*\sum_{e_i \in E(S)}w(e_i)}$
Where $f(v_i)$ is the fitness of a vertex, $w(e_i)$ is the edgeweight and $E(S)$ are the set of edges between all the vertices in ${S}$. I think for this problem we also need tunable parameters $c$ and $a$.

So in short, using the fitness as a score and the overlap as a penalty, but I'm still unsure how to turn this into a good measure.